# Toggle a class to multiple SVG paths with a specific class

Tags: jquery, svg

I am trying to toggle classes on an SVG element with Jquery but for some reason without any luck. There are multiple paths with the same class and I want to toggle them on/off all at the same time.

```
<path class="fracture-details" d="M360.5,671.5v9h-23v-20h12v11H360.5z"/>
<path class="fracture-lines" d="M285.5,673c0-0.4,0-16.5,0-24.5H246h45.5v27"/>
<path class="fracture-lines" d="M102,542.5l-2.5,3l-1,5l1,2.5l2,1l3.5,1h3l3,2l3.5-1l2-3.5l0.5-9.5l-1-7.5l-1-3"/>
<path class="fracture-lines" d="M144.5,463v-41.5"/>
<path class="fracture-details" d="M329.5,66.5L330,62l17.5,3v8.5H345l-0.5,5.5l-7-0.5L337,80l-7-1l0.5-5.5l-1-1l-6-0.5l1-5.5H329.5z"/>
<path class="fracture-lines" d="M378.5,170v-24"/>
<path class="fracture-details" d="M270.5,365.5h-11v18h11V365.5z"/>
```

The Jquery I am currently using is as follows:

```
if ($(".fracture-details").hasClass("toggleMap")) {
    $(".fracture-details").attr("class", "fracture-details");
} else {
    $(".fracture-details").attr("class", "fracture-details toggleMap");
}
```

This will be fired on click. The else part seems to work, but the first if statement never fires.

Comment: Beside the working example below, your code should work as well, if it isn't working, you are probably using an older version of jQuery. Try using version 2.2.0 or up.

Comment: This was actually an issue, although in the end I chose the solution of @prettyInPink. I was using:
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

And switching to:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Solved the problem. What is wrong with <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> If I may ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to work fine with `addClass` and `removeClass`.

```js
const fractureDetails = $(".fracture-details");
const btn = $('button');

btn.on('click', function() {
  addRemoveClass(fractureDetails, 'toggleMap');
});

function addRemoveClass(el, className){
  if( el.hasClass(className) ){
    el.removeClass(className)
  } else {
    el.addClass(className)
  }
}

addRemoveClass(fractureDetails, 'toggleMap');
```

```css
svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
.toggleMap {
  fill: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle Class</button>
<svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path class="fracture-details" d="M10,1.375c-3.17,0-5.75,2.548-5.75,5.682c0,6.685,5.259,11.276,5.483,11.469c0.152,0.132,0.382,0.132,0.534,0c0.224-0.193,5.481-4.784,5.483-11.469C15.75,3.923,13.171,1.375,10,1.375 M10,17.653c-1.064-1.024-4.929-5.127-4.929-10.596c0-2.68,2.212-4.861,4.929-4.861s4.929,2.181,4.929,4.861C14.927,12.518,11.063,16.627,10,17.653 M10,3.839c-1.815,0-3.286,1.47-3.286,3.286s1.47,3.286,3.286,3.286s3.286-1.47,3.286-3.286S11.815,3.839,10,3.839 M10,9.589c-1.359,0-2.464-1.105-2.464-2.464S8.641,4.661,10,4.661s2.464,1.105,2.464,2.464S11.359,9.589,10,9.589"></path>
</svg>
```

As mentioned by @Gleb Kemarsky, you can use built in `toggleClass`.

```js
const fractureDetails = $(".fracture-details");
const btn = $('button');

btn.on('click', function() {
  fractureDetails.toggleClass('toggleMap');
});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 50px;
  height: auto;
}
.toggleMap {
  fill: red;
}

button {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Toggle Class</button>
<svg class="svg-icon" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
  <path class="fracture-details" d="M10,1.375c-3.17,0-5.75,2.548-5.75,5.682c0,6.685,5.259,11.276,5.483,11.469c0.152,0.132,0.382,0.132,0.534,0c0.224-0.193,5.481-4.784,5.483-11.469C15.75,3.923,13.171,1.375,10,1.375 M10,17.653c-1.064-1.024-4.929-5.127-4.929-10.596c0-2.68,2.212-4.861,4.929-4.861s4.929,2.181,4.929,4.861C14.927,12.518,11.063,16.627,10,17.653 M10,3.839c-1.815,0-3.286,1.47-3.286,3.286s1.47,3.286,3.286,3.286s3.286-1.47,3.286-3.286S11.815,3.839,10,3.839 M10,9.589c-1.359,0-2.464-1.105-2.464-2.464S8.641,4.661,10,4.661s2.464,1.105,2.464,2.464S11.359,9.589,10,9.589"></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Without event listeners, this javascript doesn't do anything.

Comment: @Sean, not sure what you mean?

Comment: @Sean, on ```dom ready``` it fires it as well if needed.

Comment: You can use https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/ instead

Comment: Thanks for editing to include events.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, 100% correct, included it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is a way cleaner solution!